# Monitor thread status

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

So I have this very relevant thread I start when the program starts.
The thread is listening to events coming from a bigger system as the main thread does other stuff.
The thread should never stop working and if it does, it should be recreated and started.

I think I know multiple ways to achieve this, but I'd like to know your opinion on some things :

- Am I just striving for nothing? I mean, if I ideally try-catch all the code that can go wrong, will the thread ever betray me for no obvious reason?
- What's the best practice to do what I stated? Periodically check the thread health with another thread and a ScheduledExecutor? Implement some kind of observable-observer pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the ExecutorService which is listening to the events via `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`.
In that case You don't have to take a look at the thread if it is healthy, the ExecutorService takes care of that. The SingleThreadExecutor is responsible that only one Task (Runnable or Callable) is running at one time.

Comment: How does that work?  How does an ExecutorService "listen to the events?"

Comment: I think he meant this method over here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable)

There's a afterExecute method that one can use to take action when a thread stops.

Comment: I meant that the Runnable should work as described in the comment from @jameslarge.

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking using normal Java provided methods to view the thread state correctly, you should not have any errors. In the case that a checked exception is thrown or the thread exits for some weird reason, a try-finally block should be sufficient to start a new thread (also ensure it is non-daemon). You could use a while loop with a periodic pause, preferably using a thread scheduling mechanism such as timed `wait(...)`, or timed `LockSupport#park(...)`. You can also sleep the thread as well.

Answer (score 1):

> The thread should never stop working and if it does,...

OK, so write it so that it will never stop working.

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Message message = receiveNextMessage();
            handleMessage(message);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex);
            if (somethingTrulyHorribleHasHappened(ex)) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exit(1);
            } else {
                maybeResetSomethingThatNeedsToBeReset();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That stops working when an [Error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) is thrown. It is surprisingly easy to produce a [StackOverflowError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) from a bad recursive function, same thing for an [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) from a bad loop.

Comment: @vanOekel, from the JDK documentation, "An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch."  Sometimes a `VirtualMachineError` (e.g., `OutOfMemoryError`) is bad news only for the thread in which it was raised, but other times, it means that the whole JVM is ****ed.  You can't know:  Once it's been thrown, all guarantees are null and void.

Comment: ^^ exactly.  You have no idea what might have been corrupted by the thread failure.  Thread monitoring is a bad idea - just make them work correctly, just like the main app thread, plus 1, (shoggy)

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat pointless and futile exercise.  An app-lifetime thread should be debugged and made to not stop.  The main thread of your app lasts for the process lifetime and any other threads should be designed, tested and debugged to the same standard.

What would happen if the thread that stopped had corrupted data in other threads when it crashed?  If you just restarted it somehow, the data corruption may well make the situation worse.

Comment: Matin, you're definitely right. But keeping yourself ready for the worst sometimes is inevitable for anxious people :D Anyway, the question meant to describe not a restart, but a regeneration. The thread wouldn't be restarted but recreated anew. In this scenario (I should have mentioned that) the thread status is irrelevant and can be recreated anytime